# ColumnFilterWidgets with editor

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

How to add both functionality in single table 
  **ColumnFilterWidgets** and **editor** by **datatable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'WT<"clear">lfrtip'
} );
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? I'll be able to help you better that way.

Comment: its not working but problem is columnwidgetFilter work with index value but editor work with column name this the problem

Comment: Is your problem that the filters are not being updated on edit / create row?